# I want my button to call a method in a fragment

Tags: android, button, fragment

So I have (WorkoutList Activity) -> (WorkoutList Fragment) -> (ExerciseList Fragment) -> (addExercise Fragment)

Theres a button in AddExercise, and I want it to invoke a method in ExerciseList

The problem is that with the current set-up I'm getting `Attempt to invoke virtual method

```
void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

XML for AddExercise button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/add_exercise_button"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/add_workout_message_done"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:onClick="addExerciseDone"
    />
```

code snippet of ExerciseList inside the OnCreateView method:

```
     View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_exercise_list, container, false);
    Button AddExerciseDoneButton = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.add_exercise_button);
    AddExerciseDoneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addExerciseDone(v);
        }
    });
```

Note:
This is in response to chinmay's suggestion**
I have the viewroot set to the ExerciseList's XML file so I can make my adapter to display my listview, so I'm not sure how return the view I created so I can reference the buttons. For example, I made

```
final View tmpView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_exercise, container, false);

    Button AddExerciseDoneButton = (Button) tmpView.findViewById(R.id.add_exercise_button);
```

Comment: `setContentView` is not applicable for `Fragment`. Instead of use `onCreateView()` method. Also your question is unclear somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are getting NullPointerException because your reference to AddExerciseDoneButton is not a valid one.
You haven't specified any layout which has the button ID - `R.id.add_exercise_button` and when you are trying to use that button it will give NullPointer

instead your onCreateView should look like

```
public static class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

make your view refer to the view which onCreateView is returning it will get the button ID

for reference : http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

you are doing this

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_exercise_list, container, false);
    Button AddExerciseDoneButton = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.add_exercise_button);
```

instead of that to this

```
     View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_exercise_list, container, false);
        Button AddExerciseDoneButton = (Button) 
rootView.findViewById(R.id.add_exercise_button);
```

Comment: What if I am already returning rootView, which I am using to setup the adapter?

Comment: The button is inside a different fragment called fragment_add_exercise, do I have to put this code inside that class' onCreateView? If so I had an issue where I couldn't refer to a non-static context from a static context

Comment: Sorry so the AddExerciseDoneButton is in a seperate file than ExerciseList. I can't change the layout of rootView because I need to make changes to the list adapter. 

What I am trying now is to move the code for AddExerciseDoneButton to the addExercise class. The problem I had before when I tried this approach last time is that I couldn't reference a non-static class from a static one. The reason why I wanted to reference ExerciseList is so I can add something to the list.

Comment: I am not getting the use of that button in this fragment if that is no where related to the layout in the current fragment which you are trying to use